# A character string failed conversion to a numeric value: Teradata insert

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradata-covalent, teradatasql, teradata-aster

I am trying to execute the insert statement in teradata and getting the error message 'A character string failed conversion to a numeric value'

```
INSERT INTO USS_LOAD.RX_CLAIM (RX_CLAIM_PRCSR_PRTY_ID,RX_CLAIM_PRCSR_ORGN_NM, 
RX_CLAIM_PRCSR_PRTY_STRT_DT, RX_CLAIM_PRCSR_PRTY_END_DT,DW_UPDT_DTTM, DW_UPDT_USR)
VALUES (-104,'MeridianRx','1/23/2020','12/31/9999',current_timestamp(6),user);
```

The structure is as below

```
RX_CLAIM_PRCSR_PRTY_ID (BIGINT,NOT NULL),
RX_CLAIM_PRCSR_ORGN_NM (VARCHAR(100)),
RX_CLAIM_PRCSR_PRTY_STRT_DT (DATE),
RX_CLAIM_PRCSR_PRTY_END_DT (DATE),
DW_UPDT_DTTM (TIMESTAMP(6), 
DW_UPDT_USR (VARCHAR(72)
```

Comment: Isn't the default date format  yyyy-mm-dd?

Comment: This is a sample of the date in that table                                                            
                 1/1/1999  12/31/9999 11/11/2016 12:01:51.000000

Comment: Oh thanks, I now understand what you meant and you are correct, the date should be '9999-12-31'

Comment: Dates should be written as Standard SQL *date literals*: `date '2020-01-23'`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did that and everything ran as required. Appreciate the help.